# uniform output of signed 0.0 with ostream

Tags: c++, floating-point, ostream

Is there any standard way to set an `ostream` to print signed 0.0 uniformly without sign?

Or is this the simplest possible solution?:

```
double d = -0.0;
std::cout << ( d==0 ? 0.0 : d);
```

**Edit:**

I don't want to `abs` all, because I want to see non-0 negative numbers. I just don't want to see -0.0 (and I mean *real* -0, not very near ones). Can happen if you have e.g. a data set `double data[100];` and mirror it: `for(...) data[i]*=-1;`. And a -0.0 output because of floatfield fixed and small precision would also be OK for near 0 negative numers.

Comment: Have you tried using [`std::fabs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) to always make the value positive?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you are seeing, rather than `d` has a very small negative value, that is printed as `-0.0` (because the actual value is `-0.0000000000000617` or something like that). What hardware do you have that has negative zero? I've never seen one...

Comment: (I have seen very small numbers being printed as -0.0 tho)

Comment: @MatsPetersson No I mean real -0.0, see my edit. -0.0 with floatfield fixed and small precision is ok for e.g. -0.000000123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to print it like this

```
std::cout << ( 0.0 + d);
```

Comment: Assuming IEEE 754 compliance, this works unless you're in round-toward-negative-infinity mode.

Comment: @BrianBi and aka.nice: good answer and comment! So the proposed `std::cout << ( 0.0 + d)` is dependent of the rounding mode, while my proposed `std::cout << ( d==0 ? 0.0 : d)` is completely independent? Is there no simpler solution? Since it's an output problem is there not such thing as the `showpos` flag of `ostream`?

Comment: @mb84 1. good summary, Brian Bi is right 2. you can wait for more answers, but these are already simple IMO 3. If it ever existed, then this feature would be well hidden in any case !

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 0;
std::cout.precision(1);
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

This prints `0.0`. The `precision()` call sets the (maximum) number of decimal places to display, and the `std::ios::fixed` manipulator tell is to use all of those decimal places even if they are zero.

EDIT: If you're seeing a minus sign, as others have pointed out, it could be due to a rounding error. Note that there is also such a thing as "negative zero" in IEEE floating point numbers. If this is the real problem then you'll have to write code to check if your number is "close to" zero and if so, print it as exactly zero.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. It's avoiding the -0.0 output for "negative zero" - which I believe is what your code would produce.

Comment: @MatsPetersson See my edit. Also that's just an assumption; the OP didn't say what his actual output was or that the minus sign was the issue. He could just as easily wanted "0.0" instead of "0"; we need clarification.

Comment: Note that NOT all hardware is IEEE

Comment: @MatsPetersson Indeed, and I didn't say that it was. Anything else you'd like to nitpick to death?